# Can I connect a Twilio Device with a MediaStream in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, twilio, getusermedia, mediastream

I am using the Twilio Client [Javascript SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js-13) and would like to connect an incoming call to a MediaStream.

Currently my Twilio Client simply accepts an incoming call like this:

```js
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
  conn.accept();
});
```

The code snippets below show how I get the microphone from the browser and use it as a media stream:

```js
navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  }, (stream) => {
    this._log('Microphone connected.');
    return this.connectMediaStream(stream).then(resolve);
  }, (error) => {
  });

connectMediaStream(stream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const isMediaStream = Object.prototype.toString.call(stream) === '[object MediaStream]';

  if (!isMediaStream) {
    const error = new TypeError('Argument must be a `MediaStream` object.')
```

Now, instead of using the microphone, I would like to use the incoming call connection. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to edit the first answer, so I will add this here:

In 1.3, you can access:

- `connection.mediaStream.stream` for the local stream and
- `connection.mediaStream._remoteStream` for the remote stream

As of 1.4.14 (latest version as I write this), there are now more convenient (and documented) getter methods:

- `connection.getLocalStream()`
- `connection.getRemoteStream()`

Note that any actions you perform on these streams that modifies them will interact with the call (potentially negatively), and should be avoided unless you're quite sure you know what you're doing. :)

Comment: Hi @rrowland thanks for explaining this for us! i have a quick question though i need to perform NLP analysis on both the local and remote video streams can you please tell me that which callback can be used in order to get continuous audio streams?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Getting access to the underlying media tracks is not supported in Twilio Client. However, it's just JavaScript, so you could inspect the `Twilio.Connection` object that represents the call and eventually find the incoming audio media stream.

The specific fields are:

- `connection.mediaStream.stream` for the local stream and
- `connection.mediaStream._remoteStream` for the remote stream

Comment: Thanks @philnash. I have inspected the `Twilio.Connection` object, but couldn't find the media stream. I also contacted the guys from Twilio, hopefully they can point me in the right direction.

Comment: @NielsL You can access the local media stream via `connection.mediaStream.stream` and the remote stream via `connection.mediaStream._remoteStream`

Comment: Thanks @rrowland!